# Better performance with clap in package autocompletion

Tags: performance, shell, rust, autocomplete, clap

I make an CLI that gets the packages from yay (AUR package manager) and suggest, but I have a big problem with the clap lib:

```rust
fn package_completion() -> Result<Vec<String>, String> {
    let command = process::Command::new("yay")
        .arg("-Slq")
        .output()
        .expect("failed to execute process");

    let mut stdout = String::with_capacity(command.stdout.len());
    let mut stderr = String::with_capacity(command.stderr.len());

    stdout.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&command.stdout));
    stderr.push_str(&String::from_utf8_lossy(&command.stderr));

    if !stderr.is_empty() {
        return Err(stderr);
    }

    let mut output: Vec<String> = stdout.lines().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();

    if output.len() > 0 {
        output.remove(0);
    }

    Ok(output)
}

pub fn build_cli() -> Command {
    Command::new("yay-helper")
        .version("0.0.0")
        .subcommand_required(true)
        .arg_required_else_help(true)
        .subcommand(
            Command::new("query").about("Query a package").arg(
                Arg::new("package")
                    .help("Package to query")
                    .required(true)
                    .action(ArgAction::Set)
                    .num_args(1..),
            ),
        )
        .subcommand(
            Command::new("install").about("Install a package").arg(
                Arg::new("package")
                    .help("Package to install")
                    .value_parser(package_completion().unwrap()) # This causes the issue
                    .required(true)
                    .action(ArgAction::Set)
                    .num_args(1..),
            ),
        )
```

The program runs correctly, but the autocompletion is lazy, I need await more then 30 seconds to get the autocompletion.

I tried work with other lib (shell_completion) to make the completion and works well for Bash (the completion just generates a Bash version, I want a multi-shell version), the problem isn't the size of package list.

I need a more fastest approach to generate the autocompletion, if someone helps me, i'll be thankful.